# Combining cell values of multiple equal dimension matrices to a single matrix with each cell is a list as values of the input matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

Input:
There are three input matrices of same dimensions
3 input matrices:

```
              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          31                  4           
GeneB           5                  8 

              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA           5                 14           
GeneB           5                  8 


              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          30                 14           
GeneB           45                 7
```

output:

```
                GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          {31,5,30}         {4,14,14}          
GeneB          {5,5,45}           {8,8,7}
```

one matrix with cell value as a list of the values from the input matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapply`, and then assign the structure and dimnames as those from `matrix1`

```
matrix(
  mapply(paste, matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, MoreArgs=list(sep=",")), 
  nrow=nrow(matrix1),
  ncol=ncol(matrix1),
  dimnames = dimnames(matrix1)
)
```

Output:

```
      GeneA     GeneB    
GeneA "31,5,30" "4,14,14"
GeneB "5,5,45"  "8,8,7"
```

Comment: How about this, `matrix(paste0("{", paste(m1, m2, m3, sep = ","), "}"), nrow = nrow(m1), dimnames = dimnames(m1))`?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to hold each resulting vector within a list in a matrix. If your matrices are called `m1`, `m2` and `m3`, then you can do:

```r
m <- `dimnames<-`(matrix(lapply(1:4, function(i) c(m1[i], m2[i], m3[i])), 2),
                  dimnames(m1))
```

So that we have:

```r
m
#>       GeneA     GeneB    
#> GeneA integer,3 integer,3
#> GeneB integer,3 integer,3
```

and

```r
m[1, 1]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 31  5 30
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to R, can you please explain what 1;4 and 2 in the combine function denotes?

Comment: The 1:4 indicates the indices of your matrices (you can index matrices with a single number in R - the top left element is element 1, the first item on the second row is element 2, etc). So `lapply(1:4, function(i) c(m1[i], m2[i], m3[i]))` creates the 4 vectors we are looking for and puts them in a list. We can put this list in a matrix by wrapping the `lapply` in matrix, and specifying we want `2` rows. Finally, we give it the same `dimnames` as `m1`.